# Android code to connect PHP response changed to null

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I'm facing problem in getting a response back in android from PHP.
First, it gets the right response in try then I don't know what cause problem it goes to catch and change response to null. My PHP files are perfectly working I tested them by giving default values.

Below is the code:

This class is used to connect to server and send data to PHP:

```
public class DatabaseFunctionality extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

    int flag;
    Context context;
    String username;
    String password;
    String rname;
    String city;
    int mnum;
    String sname;
    String area;
    String sadd;
    int snum1;
    int snum2;
    String cpic;
    String ppic;

    Bitmap coverpic, profpic;

    public String resp;
    //public String r;

    StringBuilder sb;
    public DatabaseFunctionality(Context context, int f){
        this.context=context;
        this.flag=f;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if(this.flag==0){
            username=params[0];
            password=params[1];
            resp = login();
        }
        else if(this.flag==1){
            rname = params[0];
            username = params[1];
            password = params[2];
            city = params[3];
            mnum = Integer.parseInt(params[4]);
            sname = params[5];
            area = params[6];
            sadd = params[7];
            snum1 = Integer.parseInt(params[8]);
            snum2 = Integer.parseInt(params[9]);

            resp = signup();
        }

        return resp;
    }

    public String login() {
        try {
            String link = "http://192.168.0.105:80/directdukan/login.php";

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }
            Log.e("string", sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public String signup(){
        try{

            String link = "http://192.168.0.105:80/directdukan/signup.php?rname="+rname+"&username="+username+"&password="+password+"&city="+city+"&mnum="+mnum+"&sname="+sname+"&area="+area+"&sadd="+sadd+"&sanum1="+snum1+"&snum2="+snum2;//+"& cpic="+coverpic+"& ppic="+profpic;

            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(link));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
                    InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line="";

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                break;
            }

            in.close();
            Log.e("string", sb.toString());
            return sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void addproduct(){

    }

    public void searchproduct(){

    }

    public void editproduct(){

    }

    public void deleteproduct(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        this.resp = result;
    }

    public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
        try {
            byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

// Below LoginActivity & SignupActivity is used to get data from activity and send it to DatabaseFunctionality class 
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText username, password;

    Button login, signup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_signup);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String uname = username.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();
                if(!"".equals(uname) && !"".equals(pass)) {
                    DatabaseFunctionality db = new DatabaseFunctionality(LoginActivity.this,0);
                    db.execute(uname,pass);
                    if(db.resp.equals("user exist")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Username or Password is incorrect",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        username.setText(null);
                        password.setText(null);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    username.setText(null);
                    password.setText(null);
                }
            }
        });

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    public Bitmap bitmap;

    public Uri filePath;

    String imgname;

    EditText username, password, ownername, cnic, shopname, shopadd, shopphone, shopphone2, mobile;

    TextView cpic, ppic;

    Spinner citymenu, areamenu;

    Button signup2, ucpic, uppic;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        ownername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rname);
        shopname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shopname);
        shopadd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shopadd);
        shopphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shopphone);
        shopphone2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shopphone2);
        mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);

        citymenu =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.citymenu);
        areamenu = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.areamenu);

        cpic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coverpic);
        ppic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profpic);

        signup2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup2);
        ucpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadcpicb);
        uppic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadppicb);

        ucpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                imgname = getStringImage(bitmap);
                cpic.setText(imgname);
            }
        });

        uppic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                imgname = getStringImage(bitmap);
                ppic.setText(imgname);
            }
        });

        signup2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String uname = username.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();
                String rname = ownername.getText().toString();
                String city = citymenu.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String mnum = mobile.getText().toString();
                String sname = shopname.getText().toString();
                String area = areamenu.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String sadd = shopadd.getText().toString();
                String snum1 = shopphone.getText().toString();
                String snum2 = shopphone2.getText().toString();

                if(!"".equals(rname) && !"".equals(city) && !"".equals(uname) && !"".equals(pass) && !"".equals(sname) && !"".equals(mnum) && !"".equals(area) && !"".equals(sadd) && !"".equals(snum1)) {
                    DatabaseFunctionality db = new DatabaseFunctionality(SignupActivity.this, 1);
                    db.execute(rname,uname,pass,city,mnum,sname,area,sadd,snum1,snum2);
                    if(db.resp.equals("Signup Successful")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(SignupActivity.this, "Signup Successful!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fields with * are must",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fields with * are must",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        String[] items = new String[]{"*Select","Abbottabad",
                "Adezai",
                "Ali Bandar",
                "Amir Chah",
                /* snip */
                "Wazirabad",
                "Yakmach",
                "Zhob",
                "Other"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        citymenu.setAdapter(adapter);

        String[] items2 = new String[]{"*Select","Johar Town","Faisal Town", "Main Boulevard","Cantt","Model Town"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items2);
        areamenu.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: why is this tagged php ?

Comment: does http request triggered from android app receive to server? if so, do parameters have expected value?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg i'm using php to connect database with app, and i forgot to mention my php code with my question, apologies

Comment: @yılmaz yes, parameters have expected values, in android it gets right response at first but then i don't know what causing problem i goes to catch and overwrite response to null

Comment: @yılmaz problem is solved, i was calling async task and getting response on same button, as async task creates a thread, the thread was not finished yet the button gets the response and when thread finishes it again send the response which over write it and cause error. So Therefore solution for this problem is i have to block the call until the thread finishes. and for this the code is:
try{
   db.execute(uname,pass).get();
}
catch(Exception e){};

This code is entered in my login activity on function OnClickListener where i call my databaseFunctionality class